# how to get mouse offset when I've scrolled down the page in IE, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

OK...here goes. I am working on a bespoke intranet system which has a holiday calendar. 
This page is quite long and requires scrolling. This is where the problem comes in.

If I scroll down the page in IE(company policy) then click a day(this is a table cell)...a pop-up(div) should show up where I clicked. Now it shows up, but at the top of the page. Ideally its supposed to display where I click...

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm a JavaScript & Jquery novice

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

> Description: Get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for the first element in the set of matched elements.

I guess you need:

```
var offset = $(window).scrollTop()
```

Another approach would be reading your jQuery Event:

```
 $("a").click( function( jQueryEvent )
 {
     var offset = jQueryEvent.pageY;
 })
```